# How do I turn on Bluetooth in react-native if NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth" is no longer accepted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, app-store

I recently updated the iOS version of a react-native app.  I received a rejection letter stating "app-prefs:root=bluetooth" is not permitted.

I looked at the code and found that that line is responsible for turning on Bluetooth.  How would I go about turning on Bluetooth if I'm no longer able to use app-prefs:root=bluetooth?

The full code looks like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(turnOnBluetooth:(BOOL)openSettings)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth"]];
}
```

Disclaimer:  I am taking over this project and did NOT write any of the native modules.  I also have extremely limited experience working with native modules/objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```